# How genearate wear unsigned apk from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

i'm struggling to generate apk from android studio i got apks like `wear-unsigned`, `wear-debug` but when i installed these apks it shows parser error. any one suggest me please.

i followed below steps :

double click on `gradle` task - single click on build then it will generate a apk in my `output` folder

i didn't wrote nothing in my `mobile` folder i'm only wrote code in `wear` folder.

Here is my Wear Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.demo" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="20" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Hours"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please don't ask questions twice: Dub of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25886350/995926