# android wear-debug.apk shows parsing error

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

i placed configuration as wear and run it into emulator, then i found apk in my project output folder. i emailed that one, at the time of installation on wearable watch it shows `there was a error while parsing the package.` any one suggest me

Here is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.peterfriese.wearablelistviewsample" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a same error just make sure that the micro app is **signed**.

Here is a snippet of my wearable `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name" // same as the main app!
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("path/to/keystore")
            storePassword '...'
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            runProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```